# Emscripten How install old version

Tags: ubuntu, emscripten

Emscripten not installing

```
Error: No tool or SDK found by name 'sdk-1.12.0-64bit'. Ubuntu 16.04
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Why do you need an old version?

Comment: Because quake3 js support that version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the older versions have been removed, so you will need to build emscripten from source. You can download the source package from [here](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/archive/1.12.0.zip)

Steps to build it from source are available [here](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/index.html#installing-from-source)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A part of old releases of wasm-binaries is still available on https://gsdview.appspot.com/wasm-llvm/builds/ (ending / in the link is important). A little problem is that the subfolder names don't contain release number, for example for linux/ subdirectory the first link https://gsdview.appspot.com/wasm-llvm/builds/linux/11350/wasm-binaries-11350.tbz2 corresponds 1.36.11 and the last available link https://gsdview.appspot.com/wasm-llvm/builds/linux/6704/wasm-binaries.tbz2 corresponds 1.38.33.

To distinguish, which release is stored in a certain subfolder you have to download the .tbz2 and check the version inside it as follows:

```
$ tar jtfv wasm-binaries-6704.tbz2 | grep version.txt
-rw-rw-r-- chrome-bot/chrome-bot 10 2019-05-29 01:00 wasm-install/emscripten/emscripten-version.txt
$ tar jxfv wasm-binaries-6704.tbz2 wasm-install/emscripten/emscripten-version.txt
wasm-install/emscripten/emscripten-version.txt
$ cat wasm-install/emscripten/emscripten-version.txt
"1.38.33"
```

My assumption is so that the "stable" release seems to be the latest subfolder corresponding to the given release number, for example for 1.36.11 it is 12219.

After you got the proper wasm-binaries-XXXXX.tbz2 you can patch your emsdk to make it accepting another download link. All you need is to change two files.

```
emscripten-releases-tags.json
-    "1.38.33": "3b8cff670e9233a6623563add831647e8689a86b"
+    "1.38.33": "3b8cff670e9233a6623563add831647e8689a86b",
+    "1.36.11": "12219"

emsdk_manifest.json
-    "linux_url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/webassembly/emscripten-releases-builds/linux/%releases-tag%/wasm-binaries.tar.xz",
+    "linux_url": "https://gsdview.appspot.com/wasm-llvm/builds/linux/%releases-tag%/wasm-binaries-%releases-tag%.tar.xz",
```

After this patch your emsdk will be able to do this as usually (ignore "npm ci"):

```
./emsdk install 1.36.11
./emsdk activate 1.36.11
```